# How can I dynamically call a Model using Mongoid when I only know the collection name?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

lets say I have 20+ models, and one of them is called `Job`

```rb
module API
  class Job
    include Mongoid::Document
    # ...

    store_in collection: :jobs

    # ...
  end
end
```

Im working on some HTTP webhooks, and I am specifying what collection a system administrator will want to subscribe to updates for.

that said, I will know that the collection is called `jobs`

```rb
known_info = { db_name: 'x', collection: 'jobs', id: '6095d84c5be78a26cc9d837b' }

## this is the normally way one would query jobs, but I want to mimic it
## dynamically not using the Module name
API::Job.find(known_info[:id])

## a second way that will NOT work,
## this evades all API code that I have written, I need to use my ruby code in the
## model with access to the class functions
document = nil
Mongoid.default_client.collections.each do |collection|
  next unless collection.namespace == "#{known_info[:db_name]}.#{known_info[:collection]}"

  document = collection.find(_id: known_info[:id]).limit(1).first
end

## this will return the record from the database,
## but it will not send it through the model, its just the raw database value
pp document =>
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('6095d84c5be78a26cc9d837b'),
 ...
}
```

Comment: Is [tag:ruby-on-rails] involved at all? This changes the answer drastically if `ActiveSupport` is available.

Comment: You cannot call a model because it's not a method. If you have another question, edit accordingly.

Comment: you are incorrect, i was able to figure it out. @D.SM

Comment: @engineersmnky no rails

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by doing the following.

Using the namespace that the models are wrapped in, you can query the constants and narrow them down

```rb
known_info = { db_name: 'x', collection: 'jobs', id: '6095d84c5be78a26cc9d837b' }
document = nil
API.constants.each do |constant|
  module_class = API.const_get(constant)
  ## skip of the constant is not a class
  next unless module_class.is_a?(Class)
  ## skip if the class does not have a method called "collection_name"
  next unless module_class.respond_to?(:collection_name)
  ## skip if the collection does not match the known collection
  next unless module_class.collection_name.to_s == known_info[:collection]

  document = module_class.find(known_info[:id])
end

p document

## success!
```